# Get language variants of C:\Program Files

Tags: python, windows, path, program-files

I am about to distribute an app, and I am creating an installer. I know that apps in windows go to `C:\Program Files` but I am also aware that the folder changes its name depending on the language, for example, in spanish it is  `C:\Archivos de Programa`

This is quite tricky because I do not want to have to detect the language of windows and then having to create a different variable for each path in a different language. Is there any way I can get the name of that folder from python so I can just use that to create a single path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `PROGRAMFILES` environment variable:

```
>>> from os import environ
>>> environ['PROGRAMFILES']

'C:\Archivos de Programa'
```

Comment: "C:\Program Files" should exist in Windows Vista and later. If "C:\Archivos de Programa" exists, it should be a symlink or bind mountpoint (aka junction) for the real name. Check `import pathlib;` `print(pathlib.Path('C:/Archivos de Programa').resolve())`.